# External hard drive / repair missing partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I connected an external hard drive (fresh out of the box) to my server, and copied over a bunch of folders/files.  Now, re-connecting that hard drive (later), the drive won't mount, as there is no partition.

`dmesg | tail` results:

```
[ 6500.271248] ready
[ 6500.271437] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 6500.271631] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] 9767475200 512-byte logical blocks: (5.00 TB/4.55 TiB)
[ 6500.271634] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 6500.271910] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
[ 6500.271913] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[ 6500.272119] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page found
[ 6500.272206] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6500.452310]  sdi:
[ 6500.453478] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
```

`lsblk /dev/sdi` results:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdi    8:128  0  4.6T  0 disk
```

`dumpe2fs /dev/sdi` results:

```
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdi
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdi
```

`mke2fs -n /dev/sdi` results:

```
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdi
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 1220934400 4k blocks and 152616960 inodes
Filesystem UUID: bef1d7b9-cbb5-4172-ada9-c1100b44a180
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544
```

I'm running out of things to try to fix the drive and get my partition back.  Or have I lost all my data for good, now?  Appreciate any thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

The `mke2fs` output shows that the backup super blocks are stored at locations
32768 and also at 98304 and more.

You may supply this as parameter to command `e2fsck` to resolve the error:

```
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdi
```

To remount, if you do not know the directory, use:

```
cat /etc/fstab | grep -i /dev/sdi
```

Now you may mount and test the partition:

```
mount /folder
df /folder
```